# List View not populating dynamic objects at the right position

Tags: java, android, listview, dynamic

I have a custom list view which has some dynamic parts and some pre defined portions. When I populate it. The static portions appear at their correct position in the list view however the dynamic portions override the !st of the list view leaving that part of the layout in rest of the postions blank. Why is this happening?

This is my custom list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_list_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw_ch_item_label_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/default_name"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvw_ch_item_label_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+1956xxxxxxx" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#03a3d9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the getView part of the code:

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    List<String> list_of_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public CustomListAdapter(Context ctx, int res_id, List<String> objects) {
        super(ctx, res_id, objects);

        context = ctx;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < (objects.size()); i++) {

            list_of_numbers.add(objects.get(i));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;

        if (vi == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.labels_listvw_item, null);
        }

        // lv_wrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_list_items);
        LinearLayout lv_wrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_list_items);
        TextView txt_number = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.txtvw_ch_item_label_number);
        TextView txt_name = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.txtvw_ch_item_label_name);

        if (list_of_numbers.get(position).toString() == null) {
            list_of_numbers.get(position).replace(null, "");
        }

        List<String> list_of_other_columns = Utils.checkForOtherColumns(
                context, list_of_numbers.get(position).toString());
        Log.d("", "logger name=" + txt_name.getText());
        for (int i = 0; i < list_of_other_columns.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("", "logger posn is" + position);
            // LinearLayout lv_wrapper = (LinearLayout)
            // findViewById(R.id.ll_list_items);
            TextView label_txt = new TextView(context);
            // //
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams label_text_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            // //
            label_txt.setLayoutParams(label_text_params);
            label_txt.setText(list_of_other_columns.get(i));
            Log.d("", "logger label for" + txt_name.getText() + "="
                    + label_txt.getText());

            // // Log.d("", "logger lv_wrapper=" + lv_wrapper);
            // lv_wrapper.addView(label_txt);+

            if (lv_wrapper != null) {

                lv_wrapper.addView(label_txt);
            }
        }

        txt_number.setText(list_of_numbers.get(position).toString());

        txt_name.setText(Utils.getContactName(context,
                list_of_numbers.get(position).toString()));

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: coz of this  `LinearLayout lv_wrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_list_items);` the linear layout belongs to the layout that you inflated in getView??

Comment: But no it does not crash. Shall I post a screenshot as well?

Comment: @user3217900 you mean, when you update your original list, your text views become blank?